# Flutter open_file cannot open .apk file directly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently using [Open File](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package to open an apk file from local storage so I can install the said app using a button inside my flutter app and it doesn't work. I tried opening image from local storage it works just fine with this code :

```
OpenFile.open(_apkFilePath);
```

But it won't work if I do that exact code on apk file.
Then I tried using picked file just like the example from Open File like the code below :

```
Future<void> onClickInstallApk() async {
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  _apkFilePath = result.files.single.path!;
} else {}
final _result = await OpenFile.open(_apkFilePath);
print(_result.message);

setState(() {
  _openResult = "type=${_result.type}  message=${_result.message}";
});
}
```

I picked the apk file, and it works. The thing is I want apk file to be directly opened without using picked file. I thought that maybe my path was wrong, so I looked at the path gotten from picked file, turns out the file is cached on the app, with the path like this (/data/user/0/appId/cache/file_picker/AppName.apk). I am wondering is it because of the path? Or something else.
Can anyone help me with this? When the apk file failed to open, the log doesn't show anything, as if it was a success opening the file, but on the device, the error was (There was a problem while parsing the package.).

Comment: what do you expect exactly from opening an apk file with it ?

Comment: to prompt the android installer, to install the apk file. It works when I tried using picked file, the installation is prompted but not when directly without picked file

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I'm having the same issue using both open_file and open_filex and can't open an APK directly.